# Stored Procedures and asp.net programmability; variable or SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, programmatically-created, databound

Trying to display a users Lastname, Firstname  ---  Website

And I need to insert a comma and space after Lastname to a GridView.
I am trying to add a `CASE` statement in SQL and having trouble figuring it out.

Perhaps I need to use `@parameter` (scalar variable?) to abstract the
memory read from `CASE` statement; or my syntax is wrong and I just don't
understand.

```
SELECT 
    CASE
       WHEN IsNull(people_Table.firstName, '') = ''
         THEN CONCAT(people_Table.lastName, ', ', people_Table.firstName) 
         ELSE people_Table.lastName
    END as fullName, 
    people_Table.website
FROM 
    people_Table 
INNER JOIN 
    membership_Table on people_Table.ID = membership_Table.personID
WHERE 
    rectype = 'Master'
    AND membershipType = 'Business'
    AND expirationDate > GetDate()
ORDER BY 
    people_Table.lastName
```

Getting SQL Server error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'people_Table'.

Otherwise I suppose I should use an asp databoundevent in the template.

What is better for performance and security?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  The syntax looks ok at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT    ISNULL(people_Table.lastName + ', ', '') 
            + ISNULL(people_Table.firstName , '') as fullName
        , people_Table.website
FROM people_Table INNER JOIN membership_Table on people_Table.ID =
membership_Table.personID
WHERE rectype = 'Master'
AND membershipType = 'Business'
AND expirationDate > GetDate()
ORDER BY people_Table.lastName
```

### OR

```
SELECT    COALESCE(people_Table.lastName + ', ', '') 
            + COALESCE(people_Table.firstName , '') as fullName
        , people_Table.website
FROM people_Table INNER JOIN membership_Table on people_Table.ID =
membership_Table.personID
WHERE rectype = 'Master'
AND membershipType = 'Business'
AND expirationDate > GetDate()
ORDER BY people_Table.lastName
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I still get an error: Invalid object name 'people_Table'.

Comment: Ok the error suggests that the SQL Server cannot find a table with name `people_Table`, First make sure the table exists (no typo errors) , then make sure you use two part name for the table i.e `schemaName.TableName` , finally make sure the calling user has permission to read data from the table.

Comment: Thanks now it is working!  Always good to have help when learning multiple variables at once.  How do I pull AS result to GridView DataField?  www.padreguadalupe.com